# bad php class function design

Tags: php, function

While reading a book I came across the following function:

```
/*
Update records in the database
@param String $table the table being updated
@param Array $changes array of changes field => value
@param String $condition the condition
@return Boolean
*/
public function updateRecords($table, array $changes, $condition)
{
    $update = "UPDATE " . $table . " SET ";
    foreach($changes as $field => $value)
    {
        $update .= "`" . $field . "` = '{$value}', ";
    }
    //remove trailing , (comma)
    $update .= substr($update, 0, -1);

    if($condition != '')
    {
        $update .= "WHERE " . $condition;
    }
    $this->executeQuery($update);
    //Not sure why it returns true.
    return true;
}
```

Correct me if I am wrong but is this not a badly designed function with absolutely no data filtering/checking. And most of all the function returns 'true' always.

Comment: Not to mention the SQL injection vulnerability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct. It seems to be building a SQL statement by string concatenation without performing any sanitation. This *might* be acceptable if all input can be trusted, but given it's a `public` function I don't think that's the case.

The `return true` seems superfluous as it never returns anything else - the author might have intended it as a way to ensure the function completed, which implies the code it uses fails-silently instead of calling `die()` or throwing an exception.

Style-wise, the author isn't consistent with concatenation: in some places it's straight-forward concatenation with the `.` operator, in other places it uses `$placeholders`.

If `$changes` is empty then the call to `substr` will fail, doing a trim after building a list is the wrong way to comma-separate list-items. This is how I'd do it (except, never with SQL, of course):

```
$first = true;
foreach($changes as $field => $value ) {
    if( !$first ) $update .= ", ";
    $first = false;
    $update .= "`$field` = '{$value}'"; // NEVER DO THIS
}
```

Thinking about it - the only thing good about this function is it's well-documented.

Comment: True the documentation is very good but the design, well that's a different story. I believe the documentation syntax/style is phpDocumentor